# How to save a Joda-Time Period field into Room using TypeConverter?

Tags: android, jodatime

How to convert **org.joda.time.Period** in a similar way to the following code?

```
import android.arch.persistence.room.TypeConverter;

import org.joda.time.DateTime;

public class DateTimeConverter {
    @TypeConverter
    public static DateTime toDateTime(Long millis) {
        return millis == null ? null : new DateTime(millis);
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public static Long toMillis(DateTime dateTime) {
        return dateTime == null ? null : dateTime.getMillis();
    }
}
```

Comment: Which class is meant with "Joda-Time Period"?

Comment: org.joda.time.Period

Answer (score 0):

I guess it depends on the fields you want to persist. You could "serialize" them in some way and "de-serialize" back. E.g.:

```
import android.arch.persistence.room.TypeConverter;

import org.joda.time.Period;

public class DateTimeConverter {
    @TypeConverter
    public static Period toPeriod(String input) {
        String[] deserialized = input.split('_');
        return input == null ? null : new Period(deserialized[0], deserialized[1], ... );
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public static String fromPeriod(Period period) {
        return period.getDays() + "_" + period.getHours(); + "_" + ...;
    }
}
```

Maybe there's a more efficient way, but this should work.